# Upgrade from DXA 1.7(.Net) to SDL DXA 1.8 (.Net) for SDL Web 8.5 system

Tags: dxa, web8.5, upgrade, dxa-1.8

How can I upgrade DXA 1.8 where my running system is on DXA 1.7? 
I don't want to create any new Publication to upgrade the DXA 1.8. My existing publication is defined as (in master mode only):

- X_000_Empty
- X_100_Global_Functional_Master (inherits from X_000_Empty)

If i run the cms PS script :
`.\cms-import.ps1 -importType "master-only" -rootPublication "X_000_Empty" -masterPublication "X_100_Global_Functional_Master"`

My question is, how can I upgrade to DXA 1.8 without disturbing the existing Publications as I have already two Publications (X_000_Empty and X_ X_100_Global_Functional_Master) and it is part of Blueprinting and all the child Publications are associated with them.

Since, the child Publications below X_101_Global_Functional_Master and I cannot make them empty because of Blueprinting  and child Publications are associated with these two Publications. Due to that I cannot run the script :

`.\cms-import.ps1 -importType "master-only" -rootPublication "X_000_Empty" -masterPublication "X_100_Global_Functional_Master"`

as these two Publications are already exist.

Can you please suggest how could I upgrade  from DXA 1.7 to DXA 1.8 ?
As mentioned existing one is on DXA 1.7 and have a blueprint whose root publication is "X_000_Empty" in CME. I have attached the existing blueprint for the reference below :-
[image: Please see the image for my existing blueprint]

When i run the PS script command , this is the error output :-
.\cms-import.ps1 -importType "master-only" -rootPublication "X_000_Empty"
 -masterPublication "X_100_Global_Functional_Master"

[image: DXA-upgrade error message]

Comment: Do you want to upgrade or create a new publication with 1.8? Cause when you say "without disturbing these publications", that implies that you don't want to upgrade them? It would help if you share the error you get from running the script.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I want to upgrade them and I meant should not change the root and master publication and also should not change the blue printing.

Comment: The upgrade import will not empty the existing publications, it will overwrite any of the core DXA templates and tbb's. This will make sure that whatever you publish will make use of the DXA 1.8 codebase.
Next to that, you should also upgrade your web application (I believe this is the biggest part of the upgrade).

Comment: Hi @HaraldHoffelinck, Thank you for your reply. I have already upgraded the web application and now i need to upgrade DXA to CMS side. Once, I ran the above mentioned ps script and it was created default publication :-  000 Empty, 100 Master, 110 DXASite Type, 200 Example Content, and 400 Example Site, which I don't want, by the way i have rolled back the changes which occurred by the PS script. My intention to upgrade my existing publication "X_000_Empty and X_100_Global_Functional_Master".

Comment: In that case, your solution to specify the rootpublication and masterpublication names should solve this - this way, the install script will update the tbbs it finds in there.
One caveat - if you also renamed the folders where the core DXA items are located, then you might have a problem, as then the installer will create new items in these default folders, instead of updating the existing ones

Comment: Thank you for your reply @HaraldHoffelinck. Please see the error message when i ran the command :- cms-import.ps1 -importType "master-only" -rootPublication "X_000_Empty"
 -masterPublication "X_100_Global_Functional_Master"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error, it seems that there is a blueprint conflict. The error actually tells you which items is the conflicting one: `tcm:373-156169-1024`.

It seems that such *keyword* exists at a lower level (or higher) level 
 in the blueprint from where the script is attempting to create it.

Make sure that the level of the blueprint you are importing items into is the right one and is indeed the "root"/"top" level. This is a typical blueprint conflict case.

Comment: Thank you @jamie , I was able to upgrade to DXA 1.8  after deleting existing two keywords “Article and News Article” from the CMS. Rename of the keywords will not server the purpose as could see in the error log where tcm number remains same so best is to delete the existing keywords and run the cms import.