# Install DXA 2.1 in Sites 9 (NO default publication blueprint) .NET application

Tags: dxa, sdl-tridion, dxa-2.0, sites-9, publication

I would like to install DXA 2.1 in Tridion Sites 9, but don't want to have default publications with example sites (000 Empty, 100 Master, 110 DXA Site Type, 200 Example Content and 400 Example Site). I would like to create blueprint from scratch and then install DXA specific items in CM, and then run the DXA 2.1 .NET application against that. Please help

Answer (score 2):

The `cms-import.ps1` PowerShell script has an `importType` parameter which you can set to `master-only` if you want to import the DXA items in an existing BluePrint.

It also has parameters to specify your Publication names (and root Folder/SG names), so that you don’t have to rename anything before importing.

See https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v11/GUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA

Examples of how to use a `master-only` import can be found on Stack Exchange. For example: [Upgrade from DXA 1.7(.Net) to SDL DXA 1.8 (.Net) for SDL Web 8.5 system](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20646/upgrade-from-dxa-1-7-net-to-sdl-dxa-1-8-net-for-sdl-web-8-5-system)

Since DXA 2.2, you can also specify `framework-only` in case you don’t want to use the Core Module.

Answer (score 1):

Since DXA installer scripts uses simply Content Porter export packages to import DXA assests. Probably simplest way to do integrate DXA modules/templates into a existing publication is to follow these steps:

1. Rename you existing publication to '100 Master'(where you want to import DXA specific Modules/templates)
2. With Content Porter, import the package 'Master only.zip'(resides in 'SDL DXA 2.1/cms' folder) to your publication (which is renamed to '100 Master' in the previous step).
3. Rename publication back to its original name.

See this [blog](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/installing-dxa-in-an-existing-tridion-publication-structure) for a similar use case.

Hopefully future DXA release would provide better installer options to import 'framework only' DXA assets.

Comment: That “future release” is already out and is called DXA 2.2. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer from shahid, the general approach is to rename so the WebDAV urls all match up. This needs to be done each time you update DXA but I’ve never really seen a problem with it if you can freeze editors in the Cm for a couple of hours out of hours.

Another option would be to write something that will essentially search and replace the OTTB names/prefixes with your own ‘mapped’ publication paths.

Also, you could look at the mapping functionality in Content Ported and utilise this.

Comment: Or simply use DXA’s `cms-import.ps1` script. See my Answer.

Comment: Perfect - it seemed like there should be something done for this already Rick (and I've even used it in the past!!!!) +1